# Service running on RHEL7.5 is not running on RHEL8 (httpd service)

Tags: linux, rhel, apache-httpd, services, hosting-services

I have service which was working fine with RHEL 7.5, now I have upgraded to RHEL 8 and same service is failing with below status:

```
Service.service - LSB: Web Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/Service; generated)
Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Mon 2020-04-06 12:02:21 IST; 38min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 403 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/Service start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Web Server...
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain Service[403]: httpd (pid 29434) already running
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Service.service: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acquired through unsafe symlink chain:
/usr/local/apache/logs/Service.pid
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Service.service: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acquired through unsafe symlink chain:
/usr/local/apache/logs/Service.pid
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Service.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Web Server
```

THis is my Service unit placed under /etc/init.d/Service, same is done for RHEL 7.5 but there this service is working and in RHEL 8 it is not. One more thing here to note is web server is working as expected although giving me this error.

```
    #!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: 345 97 03
# description:Web Server
# processname: httpd
# config: /usr/local/Test/apache/conf/httpd.conf
# pidfile: /usr/local/Test/apache/logs/httpd.pid

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: Service
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Should-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6`enter code here`
# Short-Description: Web Server
# Description: Web Server
### END INIT INFO

LANG=en_US.iso88591
export LANG

BASEDIR=/usr/local/Test/apache
PATH=$BASEDIR/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
export PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BASEDIR/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

inst=/usr/local/Test
MIBDIRS=$inst/mibs
export MIBDIRS

case $1 in
start)
  apachectl start
  ;;
stop)
  apachectl stop
  ;;
restart)
  apachectl restart
  ;;
*)
  echo "usage: $0 { start | stop | restart }"
  ;;
esac
```

Plz help me into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see in the journal entry:

```
Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acquired through unsafe symlink chain:
```

The version of systemd in 7.5 doesn’t have the additional checks to check whether the pid for the service is outside of the systemd unit’s cgroup.

If you were to update the 7.5 system to 7.7 or later, it would also fail with the same error.

You might have better luck if you converted the sysv init script into a real systemd service unit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can you please help me know how to add the pid of my service into the systemd unit’s cgroup. Also how to convert init script into a real systemd service unit.Any reference to resources to do the same would really helpful as I could not find much.

Comment: I suggest you look at how the `httpd` package launches its service.  Here is the systemd unit that it uses:  https://git.centos.org/rpms/httpd/blob/c7/f/SOURCES/httpd.service

Comment: yes, You were right, I was using systemctl command to manage the service which is compatible with Sysv init script. One should not use that way. If want to use systemctl command to manage init service, one need to convert it to service unit by following  this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-services-with-systemd_configuring-basic-system-settings link. Thank you for you help @jsbillings